# Passing variable via submit button

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im loading content for my website from database. It loads data and fills a table.
My problem is that i have put a button next to each row. When i click on the button it has to show me the Name, Price ,Stock etc of every row.

When i click on the button i get an error.

Here you can find the code i have written in de document User_Koeken.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST[$ID])) 
{                   
$URL = $_POST['S_URL'];
$Naam = $_POST['S_Naam'];
$Inhoud = $_POST['S_Inhoud'];
$Stock = $_POST['S_Stock'];  
$Prijs = $_POST['S_Prijs'];
echo $URL."".$Naam."".$Inhoud."".$Stock."".$Prijs;                  
}
else 
{$supermarket = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "Password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("supermarket", $supermarket);
$sql = " select * from koeken";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $supermarket);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$ID = $row['ID'];
$URL = $row['URL'];
$Naam = $row['Naam'];
$Inhoud = $row['Inhoud'];
$Stock = $row['Stock'];
$Prijs = $row['Prijs'];
$_SESSION['ID']=$ID;
echo "<form action='User_Koeken.php'  method='post'>
<tr class='rien' >
<td name='S_URL'><a href=$URL><img src=$URL alt='product'></a></td>
<td name='S_Naam'>$Naam</td>
<td Name='S_Inhoud'>$Inhoud</td>
<td name='S_Stock'>$Stock</td>
<td name='S_Prijs'>€ $Prijs</td>                    
<td><input type='submit' value=$ID name='$ID'></td>
</tr>
</form> ";
};  }?>
```

Here you can find a picture of my code in color
http://postimg.org/image/n6wrb0d13/

http://postimg.org/image/n6wrb0d13/

Comment: 1. Where is $ID initialized? 2. What is the error?

Comment: Well here  < $ID = $row['ID']; > i'm using this variable as  name for my button

Answer (score 0):

`$ID` must be initialized *before* the line

```
if (isset($_POST[$ID]))
```

Otherwise, this will always return false, or an error.

Instead, use an array in your HTML names to catch the row being posted:

```
<tr class='rien' >
<td name='myform[S_URL]'><a href='$URL'><img src='$URL' alt='product'></a></td>
<td name='myform[S_Naam]'>$Naam</td>
<td Name='myform[S_Inhoud]'>$Inhoud</td>
<td name='myform[S_Stock]'>$Stock</td>
<td name='myform[S_Prijs]'>€ $Prijs</td>                    
<td><input type='submit' value='$ID' name='myform[id]'></td>
</tr>
```

and the PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['myform']) ) {
    $post = $_POST['myform'];
    $ID = $post['id'];
    $URL = $post['S_URL'];
    .... 
}
```